# Type lambda with higher kind

Tags: scala, types, dotty, scala-3, polymorphic-functions

In **Dotty** given the following:

```
object Domain {
  final case class Create(name: String) extends BaseCreate[Create] {
    override type Model = Domain
    override def service[F[_]](client: KeystoneClient[F]): CrudService[F, Domain, Create] = client.domains
  }
}
case class Domain(id: String)

class CrudService[F[_], Model, Create]
final class Domains[F[_]] extends CrudService[F, Domain, Domain.Create]

class KeystoneClient[F[_]] {
  val domains = new Domains[F]
}

trait BaseCreate[Create <: BaseCreate[Create]] {                                                                                                        
  type Model
  def service[F[_]](client: KeystoneClient[F]): CrudService[F, Model, Create]
}
```

I want to "simplify" `BaseCreate` such that I can implement `Create` like this:

```
final case class Create(name: String) extends BaseCreate.Aux[Domain, Create](_.domains)
```

I've tried:

```
object BaseCreate {
  abstract class Aux[M, Create](f: [F[_]] =>> KeystoneClient[F] => CrudService[F, M, Create]) extends BaseCreate[Create] {                                        
    type Model = M
    def service[F[_]](client: KeystoneClient[F]): CrudService[F, Model, Create] = f(client)
  }
}
```

But the compiler complains with:

```
Missing type parameter for [F[_$5]] =>> KeystoneClient[F] => CrudService[F, M, Create]
```

Which doesn't make sense to me. Whats the right syntax, if there is one?

[Link to scastie with this code](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/muOPibDeTleA3AfwtaudJg)

PS: I don't want to introduce any more type parameters to `BaseCreate`. Especially the `F` since that would mean the class `Domain.Create` would need to be `final case class Create[F[_]]` which is not at all the intended solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you confused [type lambdas](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/type-lambdas.html) with [polymorphic functions](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/4672).

A type lambda maps types to types, a polymorhic function maps values to values just type of its argument can vary.

For type lambdas you should use `=>>`, for polymorhic functions you should use ordinary `=>` (twice i.e. `[A] => (a: A) => f(a)`).

So it's supposed to be

```
object BaseCreate {
  abstract class Aux[M, Create](f: [F[_]] => KeystoneClient[F] => CrudService[F, M, Create]) extends BaseCreate[Create] {
    type Model = M
    def service[F[_]](client: KeystoneClient[F]): CrudService[F, Model, Create] = f(client)
  }
}
   
final case class Create(name: String) extends BaseCreate.Aux[Domain, Create](
  [F[_]] => (client: KeystoneClient[F]) => client.domains
)
```

but it doesn't compile in Dotty 0.28.0-bin-20200920-e99793e-NIGHTLY with error

```
Found:    Object with PolyFunction {...}
Required: PolyFunction{
  apply: 
    [F[_$6]]
      (x$1: App.KeystoneClient[F]): 
        App.CrudService[F, App.Domain, App.Create]
}
    [F[_]] => (client: KeystoneClient[F]) => client.domains
```

Seems to be a bug.