# Defining a constructor for a typeclass that takes a method with a type parameter?

Tags: scala, typeclass, polymorphic-functions

I have a situation where none of the solutions that I'm aware of feel like good ones. I am trying to define a typeclass, like the example below, where it has an abstract type `S` that must implement another typeclass (not shown) `Valid[A]`. It feels like the easiest way to do this would be to create an `apply` constructor, which will force the user to enter `S` and automatically bring in an implicit instance for `sIsValid`.

The problem with this is that function `changeType` takes a type parameter. Despite some googling I have not figured out how to write a type annotation for a function that takes a type parameter (this may be because it seems like Scala does not allow anonymous functions with type parameters). Does my approach here seem like a sensible one? If I can provide a type annotation for `changeType` then the typeclass user can still pass a non-anonymous function to the `apply` constructor, which seems like a mostly satisfactory solution.

```
abstract class IsTC[A[_], T] {
  // type S is an abstract type rather than type parameter, but must implement Valid[A]
  type S
  implicit val sIsValid: Valid[S]

  def get(self: A[T], i: Int): T
  def changeType[_T]: A[_T]
}
object IsTC {
  def apply[A[_], T, _S](
    fget: (A[T], Int) => T,
    fchangeType:  // what should this type annotation be?
  ): IsTC[A, T] { type S = _S } = new IsTC[A, T] {
    type S = _S
    def get(self: A[T], i: Int) = fget(self, i)
    def changeType[_T]: A[_T] = fchangeType[_T]
  }
}
```

Any help/thoughts gratefully received.

Comment: Actually I guess you've already asked a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64130596/dealing-with-implicit-typeclass-conflict

Comment: @DmytroMitin - thanks for the answer below - I am at work at the moment but will give it a try this evening. Yes, that question is similar, though not exactly the same. I think I have posted at least ten questions on this and closesly related topics over the past couple of months, the great majority of which you've been kind enough to respond to. I have been using a lot of trial and error to figure out what's actually possible and then what's ergonomic for the library user.

Comment: Yeah, I know about ten questions, that's ok, I'm just mentioning that you've already asked about constructor method (`instance` there, `apply` here) for a type class with polymorphic method (`get[R]` there, `changeType[_T]` here) and polymorphic function types (`[A] => (A, R) => O` there, `[X] => A[X]` here).

Comment: @DmytroMitin - Yes - in my head, this question's different from the other one. In reality, it may not be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala 2 doesn't support polymorphic functions. Polymorphic can be methods, not values. And functions [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala) values. Polymorphic functions can be emulated with wrappers

```
// for [A] => (a: A) => B[A]
trait Poly {
  def apply[A](a: A): B[A]
}
```

or

```
// for [A <: U] => (a: A) => B[A]
trait Poly[U] {
  def apply[A <: U](a: A): B[A]
}
```

like [`shapeless.Poly`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values). They generalize ordinary functions

```
trait Function[A, B] {
  def apply(a: A): B
}
```

Try

```
object IsTC {
  def apply[A[_], T, _S](
                          fget: (A[T], Int) => T,
                          fchangeType: FchangeType[A]
                        ): IsTC[A, T] { type S = _S } = new IsTC[A, T] {
    override type S = _S
    override implicit val sIsValid: Valid[_S] = ???
    override def get(self: A[T], i: Int) = fget(self, i)
    override def changeType[_T]: A[_T] = fchangeType[_T]
  }
}

trait FchangeType[A[_]] {
  def apply[X]: A[X]
}
```

Dotty [has](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/4672) polymorphic functions `[A <: U] => (a: A) => f[A](a)` of polymorphic function types `[A <: U] => A => B[A]` but there is `implementation restriction: polymorphic function types must have a value parameter` so you can't have polymorphic function type `[X] => A[X]` ([not to be confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63994512/type-lambda-with-higher-kind) with a type lambda `[X] =>> A[X]`) currently even there.

Also (besides emulation with wrappers) some polymorphic types can be expressed via existential types: `[A] => B[A] => C` (for constant `C`) is actually `B[_] => C`.

This is because `∀a: (B(a) => C)` ≡ `(∃a: B(a)) => C`.

Comment: thanks, this definitely works but it feels a bit awkward. The fact that I'm trying to do this thing which the language doesn't really support makes me think I've probably made a bad choice earlier in the design process.

Comment: @Chrisper Yeah, as I wrote in that question, since a type class has polymorphic method, most probably you don't need constructor method (`instance`/`apply`), you can just create instances via `new ...`